# Does Chromecast support Apple HLS?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

In [Chromecast's documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media) it is stated that Chromecast does support HLS streams. But I cannot make it work.

I created a simple app that have one button that initiates playback. For MP4 files it works great, but not for HLS streams. This is how I start stream:

```
btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  String url = "http://planeta-online.tv:1935/vod/mp4:tvt.russia.time_laps_in_st_piter.flv/manifest.m3u8";
  MediaMetadata movieMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);
   movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE, "Subtitle");
   movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "Title");
   movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_STUDIO, "Studio");
   movieMetadata.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse("http://cdn.planeta-online.tv/kp/app/icons/i5.png")));
   movieMetadata.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse("http://cdn.planeta-online.tv/kp/app/icons/i5.png")));

   MediaInfo mSelectedMedia = new MediaInfo.Builder(url)
    .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
    .setContentType("application/vnd.apple.mpegurl")
    .setMetadata(movieMetadata)
    .build();

    mVideoCastManager.startCastControllerActivity(MainActivity.this, mSelectedMedia, 0, true);
   }
  });
```

I enabled CORS for this stream on Wowza, but it didn't help. Changing StreamType from `MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED` to `MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_LIVE` doesn't have any effect either. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 5):

What receiver are you using? You can use either the Default receiver, or a Styled receiver; they both support HLS. Handling of adaptive streams is handled by the [Media Player Library](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/) (MPL) and if you want to write your own custom receiver, you need to use that library; we have a [sample](https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Player-Sample) that does that.

Comment: I used Styled receiver, but the problem actually was in old version of Wowza. We've upgraded it and now it works perfectly! :)

Comment: @VadimGuzev May I ask from which to which version we're talking? I wonder if I'm seeing some related issue in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901869/cast-devices-freeze-when-casting-audio-streams .

Answer (score -1):

I've found that setting the `contentType` of the stream to `"video/m3u"` or `"video/m3u8"` (depending on your format) worked for my HLS streams with the Default receiver.

Comment: It's will be worked for audio HLS streaming? I mean `audio/m3u8` would be work?